# How to use different submit buttons to send different parameter to action in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 forms, each has 2 submit buttons.

One of my forms is "Create". In this form I use no hiddenfor object and 2 submit button like this:

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="continueEditing" value="false">
      <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
      @GlobalRes.Save
 </button>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="continueEditing" value="true">
      <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
      @GlobalRes.SaveAndContinue
 </button>
```

and in server side my action signature is like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CategoryCreateVm model, bool continueEditing)
{//}
```

Everything works fine, but the problem is when I try to use same script and same code in Edit action, I face error, which says parameter named continueEditing is null!

The only difference between the `Create` and `Edit` view is that I used a hidden for object in the `Edit` view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
```

What is wrong with this form that I am not able to send extra hidden values besides parameters using submit buttons? The note is that I have to use same action for both submits.

Comment: I found my answer in this solution:https://stackoverflow.com/a/44904755/2910983

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a different name to eachone of the buttons submit.

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="continueNotEditing" value="false">
  <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
  @GlobalRes.Save
```

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="continueEditing" value="true">
  <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
  @GlobalRes.SaveAndContinue
```